# PHP formatting in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

First of all I would just like to thank you for your help!

Now before I get into this I would like to state that I am good with PHP, but know NOTHING about javascript (I know this is an issue).

So I have a .json.php file for an API that I am using that takes in information in this format:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "293",
            "title": "This is warning class event",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/",
            "class": "event-warning",
            "start": "1362938400000",
            "end":   "1363197686300"
        },
        {
            "id": "294",
            "title": "This is information class ",
            "url": "http://www.example.com/",
            "class": "event-info",
            "start": "1363111200000",
            "end":   "1363284086400"
        }
        ]
}
```

I am going to make a form that gets this information and puts it into a MySQL database, I know how to do this.  Lets say I get the values from the MySQL database and they are stored like $data['id'], where id is the value in the above file.  What I don't know is how to take those values and put it into this JSON PHP file above in the proper format.  Is it possible and how do I do it?

Comment: You may want to look into json_encode: http://ca1.php.net/json_encode , it'll convert your array to that format

Comment: You have a json as input and want to process in php?

Comment: PHP as an input but format in a json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use json_encode

Let's say you have this:

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
);
```

Then you do:

```
$json = json_encode($array);
file_put_contents('path/to/file.json', $json);
```

And you have your Json-formatted object in your file.json file.

**Note**: you can use `json_encode()` with `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option to generate a Json object (without this option it generates an array, which is what you want, but other APIs may need objects). See [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/json_encode) for more info.

Comment: Thorough response thank you very much, however if you look at the format I need, there are `[]`, how do I achieve this?

Comment: wow sorry, actually you DON'T use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT to achieve this! Sorry for typing too fast :)

Comment: And the `[]` will add themselves when you have several elements in a row in one sub-array.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong but this still does not work

Comment: Sorry I was formatting my array incorrectly!  Sorry Sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = array('success' => 0,
              'result' => array());
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json['result'][] = $row;
}
$json['success'] = 1;
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Another great simple solution,  However if you look in the format I need, there are `[]`, How do I achieve this?

Comment: I have that. `$json['result']` is an array, and each element is one row of the results.

Comment: So I can put this code right in the .json.php file?

Comment: Yes, along with the rest of the code that performs the database query.